# Rails 3.1 ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I just tried to install ckeditor in rails, however it doesn't look like its working.

Here is what I did

added these lines to my gemfile

```
gem "ckeditor", "~> 3.6.0"
gem "paperclip"
```

Then bundled installed and ran

```
rails generate ckeditor:install
rails generate ckeditor:models --orm=active_record
```

Added this file tom `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
```

And then I tried out this code:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :ckeditor %>
cktext_area_tag("test_area", "Ckeditor is the best")
cktext_area_tag("content", "Ckeditor", :input_html => {:cols => 10, :rows => 20}, :toolbar => 'Easy')
```

However, all I am getting is two textareas that do not have any editing ability. They look like normal textareas and all I can do is erase and add text.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This works like a charm, just tested it on rails 3.1.rc6. Also be cautious of the gem you are using. As of the moment of this post, the oficial gem was not working and was waiting for a pull request, so be sure to use fxposter's version of the gem in your gemfile.

https://github.com/fxposter/rails_3_1_with_ckeditor_and_carrierwave

Comment: Not working for me in rails 3.2, ckeditor javascript is loaded, but the textarea is not substituted.

Comment: Worked for me after manually copying the content of public/javascript/ckeditor from fxposter's gem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same setup as you and the same issue.  With jalagrange's example app as a comparison to mine, I eventually found the issue to be in development.rb.  I had to remove this line:

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

It worked for me with after that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I was setting it up a while ago. I gave up on the gem eventually. The problem was getting ckeditor to behave in the asset pipeline, but I had mixed results depending on the browser (of course IE was the problem). Here is what worked for me:

Download ckeditor package from their site and drop in to public/ckeditor.

Then, directly include the javascript files.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/ckeditor/ckeditor" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/ckeditor/adapters/jquery" %>
```

Not exactly elegant, but it worked and haven't had to touch it since.

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1:** Add `gem 'paperclip'` and `gem "ckeditor"` in your gemfile.

**STEP 2:** Bundle Install.

**STEP 3:** `rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip`

**STEP 4:** Place `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor) in application.rb`

**STEP 5:** Place `mount Ckeditor::Engine => "/ckeditor"` if not present already and run `db:migrate`

**STEP 6:** Open `application.html.erb` and place this `<%= javascript_include_tag 'ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %>` in header.

**STEP 7:** Place this in footer(above the body tag) in `application.html.erb`

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('textarea').length > 0) {
        var data = $('textarea');
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            CKEDITOR.replace(data[i].id);
        });
    }
});</script>
```

**STEP 8:** Restart the WEBrick SERVER.
That's it.