# Rails 3.1.2 ckeditor vendor scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ckeditor

I have a similar problem to the one enumerated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948465/rails-3-1-ckeditor), except I am not using the `ckeditor` gem. I am using the CKEditor scripts directly.

I have extracted them directly into `vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor`, and added these include stanzas to the appropriate javascript manifest file:

```
//= require ckeditor/ckeditor
//= require ckeditor/adapters/jquery
```

In development, it works perfectly fine — I assume because Rails is serving the assets directly. In production (and when I switch my local dev server to the production environment), the editor doesn't load (just blank spaces like the question linked above) and I get load errors like these:

[image: Load errors]

Those paths are obviously wrong and I'm not sure how it's working even in dev now that I think about it.

Has anybody gotten this setup to work properly, or should I suck it up and just use the gem like everybody else seems to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few hours of tinkering, I figured out that my problem was two-fold.

First, there is a CKEditor global option you can set to tell it where the base install path resides. To set that, I altered my `application.js` to add these two lines:

```
//= require_self
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/assets/ckeditor/";
```

Second, my environment config wasn't set to precompile a couple of the CKEditor files. So in `config/environments/production.rb`, I added `ckeditor/config.js` and `ckeditor/contents.css` to the array of files I'm passing to `config.assets.precompile`.

EDIT: I had to add a few more files to the precompile list than just the ones listed here. A comprehensive list would be misleading, since most of those files were from a custom theme. It's fairly simple to load up Chrome Inspector or Firebug and look at the list of assets that are still coming back 404, add those to the array, recompile, and see if that fixed it.